# text substring in th div using jquery

Tags: jquery, substring

I need to get a substring from each div element and display the substring as first 5 letters in the text.

I used jquery given below, but this code gives result as andy is displayed in all the output. but I want display result relevant , regarding substrings in the blocks.

```
$('.lblName').text($('.lblName').text().substr(0, 5))
code:<div class="name">andy oned be</div>
<div class="name">sumothad </div>
<div class="name">glimps hist</div><div class="name">sample name</div>
```

output
andy
sumot
glimp
sampl

my wrong output is
andy
andy
andy
andy

Answer (score 3):

You should use `each` to iterate over all the `.lblName`s:

```
$('.lblName').each(function() {
    var newText = ($(this).text()).substr(0, 5);
    $(this).text(newText);       
});
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/56g0vqpf/

Comment: how we use substr(0, 5)) in jquery

Comment: @saty FYI, this isn't relevant to jQuery but javascript ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
$('.lblName').text(function () {
    return $(this).text().substr(0, 5);
});
```